# how to conditionally change the fill color of export button in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have two export buttons at shown here : **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-remjyc?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js,constants%2Fzoom-level.js,stockchart%2FchartOptions.js)**

What I want to achieve is as below,

1. I want to position those two buttons to the top left corner in the same order (currently it is positioned at top right corner). If I try to resize the window, they should remain at **top left position** only.
2. Default selected button is **$** with `red` fill color. Now, when I click on **¥** button, it should remove `red` fill color from  **$** button and same `red` fill color will be applied to  **¥** button and vice versa. **Basically these two buttons are toggle buttons**.
3. Whenever you change the value from top dropdown, default selection should go **$** button always with `red` fill color.

I tried multiple things but unfortunately none of my solution is working as expected. You can play with the given link.

```
exporting: {
            buttons: [
              {
                text: '¥',
                onclick: () => {
                  exportButton.type = '¥';
                  exportButton.isDollarSelected = false;
                  alert('¥ selected');

                  setOptions({
                    // how to set exporting button fill color
                  });
                },
                theme: {
                  'stroke-width': 1,
                  fill: `${!exportButton.isDollarSelected ? 'red' : 'white'}`,
                  states: {
                    hover: {
                      fill: '#a4edba',
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                text: '$',
                onclick: () => {
                  exportButton.type = '¥';
                  exportButton.isDollarSelected = true;
                  alert('$ selected');
                  setOptions({
                    // how to set exporting button fill color
                  });
                },
                theme: {
                  'stroke-width': 1,
                  fill: `${exportButton.isDollarSelected ? 'red' : 'white'}`,
                  states: {
                    states: {
                      hover: {
                        fill: '#a4edba',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```

Comment: I've noticed you created a forum thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=49389 . Your topic will be continued there. In the future, please try to not duplicate your question on many support channels. Regards!

Comment: @magdalena This is only to reach out to more people who can help. Thanks !

Comment: @magdalena I added svgRenderes as you mentioned. I still further help in toggling : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fppihr?file=stockchart%2Fstockchart.js,constants%2Fzoom-level.js,stockchart%2FchartOptions.js